# Can not compile the 'http' crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying out Rust and trying to perform a simple HTTP GET request, following [this example](http://www.rust-ci.org/Indiv0/paste/doc/http/client/request/index.html). To start, I ran `cargo new request_learn --bin`, then pasted the example code in `main.rs` then ran `cargo build`

```
request git:(master) ✗ cargo build
   Compiling request v0.0.1 (file:///Users/soliva/Sites/rust/app/request)
src/main.rs:12:23: 12:27 error: macro undefined: 'fail!'
src/main.rs:12         Err(error) => fail!(":-( {}", error),
                                 ^~~~
src/main.rs:17:35: 17:39 error: macro undefined: 'fail!'
src/main.rs:17         Err((_request, error)) => fail!(":-( {}", error),
                                             ^~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Could not compile `request`.
```

I changed the `fail!` macro here, as it seems I don`t have it. The next build says

```
request git:(master) ✗ cargo build
   Compiling request v0.0.1 (file:///Users/soliva/Sites/rust/app/request)
src/main.rs:1:1: 1:19 error: can't find crate for `http`
src/main.rs:1 extern crate http;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `request`.
```

so I add to `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
http = "0.0.0"
```

And I build again

```
request git:(master) ✗ cargo build --verbose
    Updating registry https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
   Compiling http v0.0.0-prealpha
   Running `rustc /Users/soliva/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/http-0.0.0-prealpha/src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:20 error: The attribute license is currently unknown to the compiler and may have meaning added to it in the future
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `http`.

Caused by:
  Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc /Users/soliva/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/http-0.0.0-prealpha/src/lib.rs --crate-name http --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=bec89420f16c6bf6 -C extra-filename=-bec89420f16c6bf6 --out-dir /Users/soliva/Sites/rust/app/request/target/debug/deps --emit=dep-info,link -L dependency=/Users/soliva/Sites/rust/app/request/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/Users/soliva/Sites/rust/app/request/target/debug/deps -Awarnings` (exit code: 101)
```

*I cut some error message, as it was very long and duplicated*

Am I missing something? I am looking in to Rust modules and `cargo` documentation but I seem to be lost.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `http` crate is deprecated. Check out [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) and it would be a good idea to update your Rust version too.

Comment: rust-http is obsolete and completely unmaintained. The current recommendation is indeed to use hyper instead. The code you’re trying to build, https://github.com/indiv0/paste-rs, is also eight months old. This is an extremely long time ago in the Rust world, and very little code from then will still compile.

Comment: I did not know which one is old/new. maybe a deprecated alert in documentation would help for beginners who are trying out everything. anyway, tried `hyper` and it work well to what i wanted to. thanks for the suggestions. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, yes, [Rust-CI](http://www.rust-ci.org/).

Problem is, Rust-CI is a site from before there was support for Rust in Travis or even Cargo. In those dark, dark days, we relied on Rust-CI to detect changes in Rust nightlies and automatically update Travis CI so our build to be built with latest Rust. Also it served as a repository for docs.

Nowadays we use [Cargo](https://crates.io/) and host doc on personal Github Pages document repo.

---

Anyway as others have noted, `rust-http` crate is outdated and suggested alternative is to use `hyper` crate now.

```
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.5.0"
```

And here is a [hyper usage example](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper#example):

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::io::Read;

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::header::Connection;

fn main() {
    // Create a client.
    let mut client = Client::new();

    // Creating an outgoing request.
    let mut res = client.get("http://www.gooogle.com/")
        // set a header
        .header(Connection::close())
        // let 'er go!
        .send().unwrap();

    // Read the Response.
    let mut body = String::new();
    res.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    println!("Response: {}", body);
}
```

Comment: There are also [some Hyper usage examples available](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper#example).

Comment: @Shepmaster Neat. I'll link it and inline the source.